# Avoid breaking on generated code

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, visual-studio-debugging

I am using some external code which when called with certain parameters throws an exception which can be ignored.  Unfortunately I can not change this external code for various reasons.

I have created a wrapper method which looks something like this:

```
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static bool TryGetXXX(string input, out string output)
    {
        try
        {
            output = MethodThatSometimesFails(input);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            output = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static string MethodThatSometimesFails(string input)
    {
        // Don't want this to cause a break
        // but can not put the attribute on this method
        throw new Exception("couldnt deal with your request");
    }
```

Unfortunately though, the external code will still break at the exception inside `MethodThatSometimesFails`.  The `[DebuggerStepThrough]` will only avoid debugging the code above, but the called code will still throw.

What I would like is that the code just runs even with all of check boxes on the "Exceptions..." window checked.  Is there an attribute which can do this?

If there is no attribute I could create a project containing these classes / methods and exclude the entire project. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what about your Tools->Optoins->Debugging->Break when exceptions cross AppDomain setting? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/a4c32d57-9046-41c4-bf8b-3718ff474847/

Comment: You get this because of a debugger configuration setting: Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox.  There isn't anything you can do but untick that checkbox.

Comment: I want other exceptions outside of this method to be thrown and for me to see them, so I suppose not unticking the thrown checkbox is the purpose of this question.  As a developer, I would like to always know if exceptions in parts of my code are being thrown during development stage.  The tyoe of the error is ApplicationException, so it is quite a wide range I would have to limit by unchecking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution for this.  In the end the only option was to put the TryGet into another DLL!

Answer (score 1):

Try mark method or class with [DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggernonusercodeattribute.aspx)

Comment: Check status of the options in Visual Studio in the Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the valid parameters are, check them before calling the function. If they are invalid, don't call the function.

Try to be optimistic and eliminate the dependency on exceptions which can be costly.

Comment: My understanding is the OP can't do that. He is trying to deal with this situation that requires him to tolerate exceptions.

Comment: @usr i mean in the `TryGet...` method.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, unfortunately there is an entire library which is called through this method and it is the job of the library to know what is valid and what isnt.  Unfortunately no TryGet is provided by them.

Comment: can't you just avoid some common cases?

Comment: Its very much upto the library what the cases are.